# Open a incremental version file with PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a folder with several files like:

```
text.txt | modified 14h30
info.ini | modified 14h30
trail.txt | modified 14h30
trail.txt.1 | modified 14h35
trail.txt.2 | modified 14h32
```

what I need are two methods for opening the latest trail.txt (since this is a log from another software and I am still not sure how to choose the active one)

I'd need a function to open the latest trail.txt.X (highest number) and a different one to open the last modified trail.txt.

I have tried to search a lot of functions but I could not do it, I hope someone can help me. What I have so far is a basic open

```
$trail_file = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\\trail.txt.20";
$fh = fopen($trail_file, "r");
if ( $fh ) {
  while ( !feof($fh) ) {
    $line[] = fgets($fh);

  }
  fclose($fh);
```

---

I have now the following working code:

```
$carpeta="C:/Users/Public/Documents/";
if(is_dir($carpeta)){
 $files_in_dir = array();
        if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
            while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){             
                 if(preg_match('/trail.txt/six', $file))  
                   $files_in_dir[filemtime($carpeta.'/'.$file)] = $file;  //i missed that important part
            }
            closedir($dir);         
        }
    }
 // sort
ksort($files_in_dir);
// find the last modification
$last_file = end($files_in_dir);
echo $last_file."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [filemtime](https://www.php.net/filemtime)

EDIT

i found a solution in a spanish forum, so i dont copy all the code, i missed a few lines..
now it should work

```
$carpeta="C:/AppServ/www/blog/images";
if(is_dir($carpeta)){
 $files_in_dir = array();
        if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
            while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){             
                 if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.htaccess')  
                   $files_in_dir[filemtime($file)] = $file;  //i missed that important part

                 $number_infile = explode(".", $file);        //add this 2 lines to get the highest number)
                 $files_in_dir_highest_number[$number_infile[2]] = $file;
            }
            closedir($dir);         
        }
    }
 // sort
ksort($files_in_dir);
// find the last modification
$last_file = end($files_in_dir);
echo $last_file."<br>";

foreach($files_in_dir as $file) {
    $lastModified = date('F d Y, H:i:s',filemtime($file));
        if ($file == $last_file) {
            echo "$file$lastModified";
        }
}  

//this lines get the highest name
    ksort($files_in_dir_highest_number);
    $file_highest_number = end($files_in_dir_highest_number);
    echo $file_highest_number."<br>";
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I open the last trail.txt.* ?
I had an array like
    [0] => trail.txt.1    [1] => trail.txt.3    [2] => trail.txt4    [3] => trail.txt.2

how could I sort it out and open the latest one?

Comment: I've edited the question with the new code, I can't sort out the last file

Comment: sorry but it Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for...
but if you check my code you can see I'm trying get the latest file by number instead of last modified date.
I'm having a problem since the last file is trail.txt.22 and it shows trail.txt.9 as last.

Using the code in the bottom of my question, how can I just order the array and get the file with the highest number? (trails.txt.XX)

Comment: awwww, I thought you wanted the last modified

Comment: @RúbenInácio, look, "I'd need a fuction to open the latest trail.txt.X (highest number) and a different one to open the last modified trail.txt." from your post... do this code work for the last part?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have explained it better. However I managed to use your code, but I had to make some changes for it to work. I had to add the directory to the $file so the filemtime could work. I've added the code to the question

Comment: @RúbenInácio now, you can get the highest number